# Masked Array - Count the value in a specific interval

Tags: python, numpy, masked-array

I am quite new to masked arrays and satellite data. I am trying to figure out how to count the number of elements in a masked_array that are in between an interval e.g. say 40  to 80.  This is what I have:

This is the summary of my masked array named 'grid'.

```
masked_array(
  data=[[[120, 120, 120, ..., 200, 200, 200],
         [120, 120, 120, ..., 200, 200, 200],
         [120, 120, 120, ..., 200, 200, 200],
         ...,
         [120, 120, 120, ..., 200, 200, 200],
         [120, 120, 120, ..., 200, 200, 200],
         [120, 120, 120, ..., 200, 200, 200]]],
  mask=False,
  fill_value=999999,
  dtype=uint8)
```

I want to calculate the % of elements in the masked_array that are between 40 and 80. I tried.

```
masked  = ma.masked_where((grid >= 40) & (grid <= 80), grid)
green_ratio = masked.count()/grid.count()
```

but this is returning 1 which is quite unlikely given that I see that there are values larger than 120.

Any idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`masked.count()` still gives you the total unfiltered number of values which is of course equal to `grid.count()`.

Since `masked.mask` is a boolean array, you could do for example `masked.mask.sum()/grid.count()` to limit the ratio to those values which meet your condition.

Comment: It worked, thanks! - also I noticed (1-masked.count()/grid.count()) also worked.